# Open .wordcontainer produced by SAP?

Tags: microsoft-word, compatibility, sap

SAP produces *xxx.wordcontainer* files from MS Word documents. Is it possible to recover and further work on the word document from these *.wordcontainer* files

- outside and independent from SAP
- on Linux or Windows (or in theory Android)
- preferably with free software, (or using software
  usually available independent from specialization, e.g. MS office)?

When I rename such a file to *xxx.zip*, 7zip opens it and shows folders (*Macros, ObjectPool*...) und files (*Data, WordDocument*...). I cannot open any of these with MS word, but I can open *WordDocument* with standard editor as plain text only, and it seems to contain word document content. *WordDocument* is not a zipped structure itself (cannot open it after renaming to *.zip*).

I'd like to recover the formatted word document.

Comment: did you try to change the extension to .DOCX?

Comment: @Suncatcher Good point - I tried, .docx did not work... then I thought again and realized that not every SAP instance may be completely up to date to the most recent incredible edge of technology ... and tried .doc - Yep, worked! Not exactly sure why a .doc opens when renamed to .zip (with files saved myself from Word as .doc this does not work), but anyway. You may post as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably these files were produced in some standard SAP control like [SAP Document Container](https://help.sap.com/doc/7aca2e29728810148a4b1a83b0e91070/1511%20002/en-US/4932f23de8c45aaae10000000a42189d.html) or some else. Usually they are normal doc files but with another extension.

It is a usual (weird) SAP practice to name file with some content (csv, xls) [with a wrong extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65409969/excel-file-downloaded-from-sap-is-not-getting-recognized-in-my-vba-code).